# Edittext jumps to next edittext after reaching the maximum edittext length

Tags: android, android-edittext

In my layout I have 4 edittext.. I need to jump to the next edittext after reaching the maximum length . But there is a problem..How to do it?.. Please anybody help me to do this...

Comment: In your java code set max length not in your layout..
and check if length is equal to set by you override next button of android keyboard..

Comment: Amith it is very easy you have to put addTextChangedListener whenever the length is as max limit set the focus on other Edittext

Answer (score 3):

On reachin the count you change the focus of the edittext to the next one

```
Edittext edt1;
Edittext edt2:
//mount the views to java from xml
edt1.addTextChangedListener(this);  
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
        int after) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


}
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
if(count==length){
edt2.requestFocus()
}
}
```

Comment: Note that if you want to check the total length of the string in the edit text, your if clause should be more like `if (s.length() == length)`

Answer (score 2):

This approach works by inspecting the length of inputted text after the text field changes.

```
EditText textBox1;
EditText textBox2;

textBox1.addTextChangedListener(this);

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
   if (s.length() == MAX_LENGTH) {
      textBox2.requestFocus();
   }
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
   // nil
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
   // nil
}
```

Comment: I am using a recyclerView, and working within it's adapter. For some reason, using the onTextChanged() method will not work for me. However, afterTextChanged() worked like a charm. Thank you for your input here.