# Android: Ensuring EditText boxes fit horizontally across screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I am trying to allign **3 EditText boxes** across the screen horizontally in my activity so that the user is able to enter data.

Currently the code that I am implementing doesnt allow the 3 boxes to fit on the screen. Only 1 box and half of the other are visible

How can I adjust my current code so that all 3 Edittext boxes are **visible** to the user?

Note: The button and textView at the bottom of the layout are also currently **not** visible, eventhough they should be under the 3 horizontally alligned Edittext boxes.

**Current XML Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSearchDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" Enter Date to search..."
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >



     <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etEnterSpecificyear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="" >
    </EditText>

     <TextView
        android:layout_width="3dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etEnterSpecificMonth"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="" >
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="3dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

     <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etEnterSpecificDay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="" >
    </EditText>

     </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSearchDate"
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Submit" 
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSearchResultsDate"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:maxLines="30"
        android:minLines="5"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:text=" Results..."
        android:textSize="15dp" />



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This sounds like a job for http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each of your edittext make this:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etEnterSpecificyear"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:hint="" >
</EditText>
```

And delete the TextView's that are in between the EditText's

Comment: Thank you, However I still cannot see the button in my layout when I use this solution?

Comment: It's because the Horizontal LinearLayout you are using has the height `match_parent` it makes it strech all the way down so the button doesnt appear. Change it to `wrap_content`

Comment: Thank you :) this has solved both problems. This is the accepted answer!

Comment: is there a way to move automatically to the next EditText box once the user has entered what they want in the first?

Comment: Add this attribute to your EditText `android:imeOptions="actionNext"`. This will make it go to the next one in the same ViewGroup when the user clicks enter. If you want you can use `android:maxLength="2"` and then implement a listener that automatically switches to the next one, when the maximum length has reaced. Look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17802250/1842694)

Comment: Thanks, I was able to implement the functionality using the example you gave. However it only changes focus from the 1st ro 2nd. It doesnt work then when I try to change from 2nd to 3rd?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are using **android:ems="10"** in EditText properties. This one makes the minimum width of the EditText to be exact ten "M" characters. If this is your requirement I would suggest to use **android:orientation="vertical"** in the parent LinearLayout. So your final layout will look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSearchDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" Enter Date to search..."
        android:textSize="15dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etEnterSpecificyear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="">
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etEnterSpecificMonth"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="">
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etEnterSpecificDay"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="">
        </EditText>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSearchDate"
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Submit"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSearchResultsDate"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:maxLines="30"
        android:minLines="5"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:text=" Results..."
        android:textSize="15dp"/>


</LinearLayout>
```