# Edittext jumps to next edittexts after reaching the maximum edittext length

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

My question is very similar to this post: [Edittext jumps to next edittext after reaching the maximum edittext length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17801945/edittext-jumps-to-next-edittext-after-reaching-the-maximum-edittext-length)

But, whatever I try to do, I'm not able to jump third edittext as shown in the pic below. I write 10 to the first edittext and it automatically moves to the second edittext but when I write 12, it doesn't move to third edittext. I tried a couple of things but couldn't handle it. I need a simple solution for this problem up to 10-15 edittexts. Can anybody help me about syntax? Thanks.

[image]

Here is my activity main xml

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext1"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:maxLength="2"
    android:hint="1"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext2"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:maxLength="2"
    android:digits="0123456789 "
    android:hint="2"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext3"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:maxLength="2"
    android:digits="0123456789 "
    android:hint="3"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

And here is my main activity

```
package com.example.serkan.justtry;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TextWatcher {
    EditText edt1;
    EditText edt2;
    EditText edt3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    edt1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
    edt2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext2);
    edt3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext3);

    edt1.addTextChangedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
    if (edt1.length() == 2) {
        edt2.requestFocus();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the listner to edt2 as well

```
    edt2.addTextChangedListener(this);
```

just replace

```
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        if(edt1.getText().hashCode() == editable.hashCode()){
            if (edt1.length() == 2) {
                edt2.requestFocus();
            }
        }
        else if( edt2.getText().hashCode() == editable.hashCode()){
            if (edt2.length() == 2) {
                edt3.requestFocus();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: remove the  else if  and have only if check the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Add this as an inner class in your Activity:

```
private class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    private final int maxLength;
    private final EditText next;

    MyTextWatcher(int maxLength, int nextId) {
        this.maxLength = maxLength;
        this.next = (nextId != -1) ? findViewById(nextId) : null;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        if (editable.length() >= maxLength && next != null) {
            next.requestFocus();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        // do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

And then set it up for each EditText like this:

```
edittext1.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(2, edittext1.getNextFocusDownId()));
edittext2.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(2, edittext2.getNextFocusDownId()));
edittext3.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(2, edittext3.getNextFocusDownId()));
```

This depends on setting the `nextFocusDown` attribute in your layout:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext1"
    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/edittext2"
    .../>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in XML file.
Just try following code in MainActivity.java

1. Add TextChangedListener to second edittext

   `edt2.addTextChangedListener(this);`
2. Insert following code in onTextChanged method of textwatcher

   ```
   @Override
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

   }

   @Override
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
           if(edt1.hasFocus())
       {
           if(edt1.getText().toString().length()==2)     //size as per your requirement
           {
               edt2.requestFocus();
           }
       }
       if(edt2.hasFocus())
       {
           if(edt2.getText().toString().length()==2)     //size as per your requirement
           {
               edt3.requestFocus();
           }
       }

   }

   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

   }
   ```

I hope this answer will solve your problem :)

Answer (score -1):

You didin't set the `TextChangedListener` to the other 2 EditTexts.
The listener doens't know when it must change the focus from `edt2` to `edt3`.

Add the listener to the `edt2` on your `onCreate`.

```
edt2.addTextChangedListener(this);
```

And update the `afterTextChanged`

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

    if (editable == edt1.getEditableText()) {
        if (edt1.length() == 2) {
            edt2.requestFocus();
        }
    } else if (editable == edt2.getEditableText()) {
        if (edt2.length() == 2) {
            edt3.requestFocus();
        }
    }
}
```

I didn't test. :)